# Mail app won't show messages

Tags: release-hera, pantheon-mail

I set up my IMAP account and everything looks like it worked. However nothing will appear in the right two columns, even though my message count appears like the app is grabbing the correct number. Is this is known issue with Mail?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Reboot... Nothing I tried worked until I rebooted. After a reboot, Mail displays properly.

--original post--
No idea, but the same thing is happening to me. I'll update if I find a fix...

Currently I'm stuck trying to reset pantheon-mail completely. I can't remove the last account. I've deleted the following folder: **~/.local/share/pantheon-mail**

I've also deleted **~/.local/share/geary** and **~/.local/share/evolution** for good measure.

I've removed and reinstalled using apt and -f, etc.